# How do I configure Apache Flink's StreamingFileSink to use watermark for rolling in-progress files?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Kafka topic with a bunch of different events. Each event has an `eventType` and `eventTs`. I'm implementing a Flink job that reads these events from Kafka and stores them in S3 as `/eventType=XXX/hour=XXX/foo.json.snappy` files. In order to do it I use `StreamingFileSink` which rolls a file if the size of an archive exceeds 128M and based on processing time since creation of the file and since last activity.

```scala
class BatchingCheckpointRollingPolicy[IN, BucketID](val maxSizeBytes: Long,
                                                    val inactiveBucketCheckInterval: Long,
                                                    val maxIntervalSinceBucketCreationMillis: Long)
  extends CheckpointRollingPolicy[IN, BucketID] {

  override def shouldRollOnEvent(partFileState: PartFileInfo[BucketID], element: IN): Boolean = {
    partFileState.getSize >= maxSizeBytes
  }

  override def shouldRollOnProcessingTime(partFileState: PartFileInfo[BucketID], currentTime: Long): Boolean = {
    (currentTime - partFileState.getLastUpdateTime >= inactiveBucketCheckInterval) ||
      currentTime - partFileState.getCreationTime >= maxIntervalSinceBucketCreationMillis
  }
}
```

The problem arises when I want to use this job for backfilling data from Kafka (e.g. for the last 7 days) or I start the job from earliest offset — since the triggers in `StreamingFileSink` are based on processing time and not event time, I'm getting many buckets opened (Flink processes records faster than they get flushed) which leads to OOM errors. Each bucket has a `CompressionStream` opened with 256K buffers in direct memory.

What am I missing here? How do I properly set up my pipeline so that the buckets are flushed properly during the backfill?

Comment: If you know the data is coming from Kafka in increasing event time order, couldn't you modify `shouldRollOnEvent()` to also roll when you get an event that's in a new hour bucket?

Comment: @kkrugler how do I do it? The event from the next hour will arrive to a different bucket (the one that is for the next hour)

Comment: What is the events throughput rate ? If the events are coming in increasing time order and you are sure, for example, that you have an event every second, then you could probably decrease the inactiveBucketCheckInterval to about a couple of seconds thus guaranteing that the bucket will be closed no later then in a couple of seconds after the last event in this our comes. This way you probably won't have too many open buckets open.

Comment: @MikalaiLushchytski I agree that it might be a good solution, but my goal is to have files as close to 100M as possible since I store the data in S3 and use it for Spark processing later.

I have ~20G of raw input every hour.

Comment: @bu99ycr0c0d11e, could you please specify how much RAM you have and what are your memory management settings ?

Comment: @bu99ycr0c0d11e, also, could you please provide if possible some more details like flink version you are using, sink parallelism, number of task managers, rough estimate for different event types per hour ? Thank you.

Comment: @MikalaiLushchytski Flink 1.11.1

`taskmanager.memory.managed.size: 0m`
`taskmanager.memory.task.off-heap.size: 2000m`
`taskmanager.memory.process.size: 7200m`

Comment: Flink is running in k8s, one task manager per Pod, Pod has limit of 7.5G. 3 task managers, one slot per task manager. Not sure about sink parallelism and if I encountered such option so I assume it's default. As far as event types are concerned — we have ~1000 different event types

Comment: @bu99ycr0c0d11e, haven't you considered as an alternative to try to partition data between sink instances based on bucket partitions? I.e. send 1/3 of events with eventType hash code, for instance, within the same range, to a first sink and so on ? Right now every sink instance gets buckets for all partitions so you hold in memory 3x times more compared to approach with smart partitioning.

Comment: @MikalaiLushchytski unfortunately, that would lead to data skew since events are not balanced in terms of frequency

Comment: @bu99ycr0c0d11e, what is the expected behavior then ? From what I can understand, it's not possible to flush the open bucket when we get the event for the next hour as other kafka partitions may still produce events for the same hour. As an alternative, if you only want to solve the OOM issue, you could possibly try to check the available memory inside of `shouldRollOnProcessingTime()` and if it reached some threshold, for instance, just 20% left, then flush the biggest buckets - for instance, the buckets greater then `100MB` in size.